# random is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a modal that uses the Math.random to generate random ids.

```
    function new_modal(head, content, button){

    var random = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);

    var modal_html = '<div id="myModal_'+ random +'">' +
     '<div id="outer">' +
      '<div id="inner">' +
       '<div id="top">'+head+'</div>' +
        '<span class="bOk"><img class="btnClose" src="#"></span>' +
       '<div class="modalCnt">'+content+'</div>' +
       button +        
      '</div> <!-- Inner -->' +
     '</div> <!-- Outer -->' +
    '</div>';

    $('body').append(modal_html);
  // Close the Modal
    $('#myModal_'+ random +' span').on('click', closeFunction);
    return 'myModal_' + random;  

}
```

And I have a close function, but when that runs is gives me "random is not defined", when the code under alert(It's true) runs. Why is that? When the code lies under the new_modal function it works perfect, but when I put it outside that function and into its own function it's not working.

```
    function closeFunction() {
    var check = $(this);
        if(check.hasClass("bOk") || check.hasClass("btnText") === true) {
            alert("It's true");
            $(this).closest('#myModal_'+ random).hide();
        } 
        else {
            alert("It's false, do something else");
            return false
            }
}
```

Comment: random is local to new_modal function. How you imagined that it will be accessible from outside that function?

Comment: You use of ID's is scary.. If you used classes, you wound't even need the `random`,.. just add a class say "modal", you could then just do -> `$(this).closest('.modal").hide();`

Comment: I do need random, because I need to be able to get modals to lay on top of another. I could of course use class + random instead of id + random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [vicbyte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975136/random-is-not-defined/46975196#46975196) pointed out, this is a matter of scope, `random` exists only inside `new_modal` function so it can't be accessed outside this function. You can embed your function directly inside the `.on`  call like this :

```js
function new_modal(head, content, button) {

  var random = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);

  var modal_html = '<div id="myModal_' + random + '">' +
    '<div id="outer">' +
    '<div id="inner">' +
    '<div id="top">' + head + '</div>' +
    '<span class="bOk"><img class="btnClose" src="#"></span>' +
    '<div class="modalCnt">' + content + '</div>' +
    button +
    '</div> <!-- Inner -->' +
    '</div> <!-- Outer -->' +
    '</div>';

  $('body').append(modal_html);

  // Close the Modal
  $('#myModal_' + random + ' span').on('click', function() {
    var check = $(this);
    if (check.hasClass("bOk") || check.hasClass("btnText") === true) {
      alert("It's true");
      $(this).closest('#myModal_' + random).hide();
    } else {
      alert("It's false, do something else");
      return false
    }
  });

  return 'myModal_' + random;
}
```

I prefer this approach instead of the global variable one since you don't pollute the global scope and allows you to open multiple modals at the same time.

But since you need to put this function outside, create a closure like this :

```js
function new_modal(head, content, button) {

  var random = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);

  var modal_html = '<div id="myModal_' + random + '">' +
    '<div id="outer">' +
    '<div id="inner">' +
    '<div id="top">' + head + '</div>' +
    '<span class="bOk"><img class="btnClose" src="#"></span>' +
    '<div class="modalCnt">' + content + '</div>' +
    button +
    '</div> <!-- Inner -->' +
    '</div> <!-- Outer -->' +
    '</div>';

  $('body').append(modal_html);

  // Close the Modal
  $('#myModal_' + random + ' span').on('click', function () {
    closeModal($(this), random);
  });

  return 'myModal_' + random;
}

function closeModal(element, random) {
  var check = element;
  if (check.hasClass("bOk") || check.hasClass("btnText") === true) {
    alert("It's true");
    check.closest('#myModal_' + random).hide();
  } else {
    alert("It's false, do something else");
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats what I had, and it works great. But I need the close function outside unfortunately.

Comment: Great, I had to change $(this).closest('#myModal_' + random).hide(); to check.closest('#myModal_' + random).hide(); Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its called variable scope. :)
If you declare a variable (using var keyword) inside one function it will not be accessable in another.
If you want to use the same random in both functions either declare it globally (before functions) or pass it via arguments.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
 var random="";
 function new_modal(head, content, button){

     random = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);

    var modal_html = '<div id="myModal_'+ random +'">' +
     '<div id="outer">' +
      '<div id="inner">' +
       '<div id="top">'+head+'</div>' +
        '<span class="bOk"><img class="btnClose" src="#"></span>' +
       '<div class="modalCnt">'+content+'</div>' +
       button +        
      '</div> <!-- Inner -->' +
     '</div> <!-- Outer -->' +
    '</div>';

    $('body').append(modal_html);
  // Close the Modal
    $('#myModal_'+ random +' span').on('click', closeFunction);
    return 'myModal_' + random;  

}

function closeFunction() {
    var check = $(this);
        if(check.hasClass("bOk") || check.hasClass("btnText") === true) {
            alert("It's true");
            $(this).closest('#myModal_'+ random).hide();
        } 
        else {
            alert("It's false, do something else");
            return false
            }
}
```